# How to merge two array columns into one array with duplicates removed in spark with java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I want two merge two arrays into one array with duplicates removed in spark 2.2 with java.

Input spark dataset below.

```
 Dataset.show

col1    | col2 
[1,2,3] | [2,3,5]
```

Expected output -

```
 Dataset.show

    col1    | col2          | col3
    [1,2,3] | [2,3,5]       |[1,2,3,5]
```

How can achieve this spark java?.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use an UDF:

```
val mergeArrays = udf((a: Seq[String], b: Seq[String]) => (a ++ b).toSet.toSeq)
```

Then, assuming your input is

```
val df = Seq((Seq(1,2),Seq(2,3))).toDF("col1", "col2")
```

you can merge the arrays with

```
df.withColumn("col3", mergeArrays($"col1", $"col2"))
```

resulting in

```
+------+------+---------+
|  col1|  col2|     col3|
+------+------+---------+
|[1, 2]|[2, 3]|[1, 2, 3]|
+------+------+---------+
```

EDIT: Java version. As expected, it's **way** uglier, so if you can use Scala, use that instead.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF2;
import scala.collection.Seq;
import java.util.*;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes.*;
import static scala.collection.JavaConverters.*;
Dataset<Row> data = spark.createDataFrame(
        Collections.singletonList(RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList(1, 2), Arrays.asList(2, 3))),
        createStructType(Arrays.asList(
                createStructField("col1", createArrayType(IntegerType), true),
                createStructField("col2", createArrayType(IntegerType), true))));
spark.sqlContext().udf().register("udfMerge", (UDF2<Seq<Integer>, Seq<Integer>, Seq<Integer>>) (s1, s2) -> {
    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
    s.addAll(asJavaCollectionConverter(s1).asJavaCollection());
    s.addAll(asJavaCollectionConverter(s2).asJavaCollection());
    return collectionAsScalaIterableConverter(s).asScala().toSeq();
}, createArrayType(IntegerType));
data.withColumn("col3", functions$.MODULE$.callUDF("udfMerge", functions$.MODULE$.col("col1"), functions$.MODULE$.col("col2"))).show();
```

Comment: I have only used Spark with Scala, but I don't see why this wouldn't work in Java. The syntax won't be as concise, and you'll be missing on some implicits, too, but all Scala classes can be referenced from Java

Answer (score 2):

Since Spark 2.4, you can use [`array_union`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#array_union-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) function. It merges two arrays without duplicates:

```java
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_union;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

dataframe.withColumn("col3", array_union(col("col1"), col("col2")));
```